# pandas cast any value to bool (missing or zero)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

In python it is of no problem to write something like

```
if a: ...
```

even if `a` is an integer (e.g. 0) or a string (e.g. empty string), in which cases it will be cast to false.

However

```
dtype_dict = {'type': str, 'exclude_trial':bool}
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', dtype=dtype_dict)
```

returns warning

```
ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of bool for object dtyped data in column 26
```

which is totally unclear and terribly annoying.

The column "exclude_trial" contains values either '' (empty string) or '0' or '1'. Of course it shall just be simply casted as per the normal behavior as otherwise also usual. ('','0' -> false, 1->true)

Answer (score 2):

After reading the data, you can use `.astype(bool)` on your DataFrame to convert it using the equivalent of `bool(x)` where x is the value in each cell.

However you need to be **very** careful. `pandas` has a lot of automatic NaN handling, and this means that the empty string will often get read in and coerced to NaN, which is problematic as `bool('')` is `False` while `bool(np.NaN)` is `True`. Even specifying the dtype doesn't protect against this, but you can use `na_filter` to ensure it doesn't change the empty string.

**Sample Data:** `test.txt`

```
col1,col2,col3
True,1,
False,0,
True,1,1
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', na_filter=False)
#    col1  col2 col3
#0   True     1     
#1  False     0     
#2   True     1    1

df = df.astype(bool)
#    col1   col2   col3
#0   True   True  False
#1  False  False  False
#2   True   True   True

df.dtypes
#col1    bool
#col2    bool
#col3    bool
```